# I only want to get the rotation status of the device without rotating the screen at Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, camera

I am building a multi-page application with Xamarin.Forms.
Basically, this is a non-rotating setup.

```cs
[Activity(ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

However, we want to get the rotation status of the device only on the camera page.
So, on the camera page, we call the following method

```cs
private int  GetDeviceRotation()
{
    var activity = (Android.App.Activity)this.owner.Activity;
    activity.RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Sensor;

    // Get Metrics
    var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
    var rotation = mainDisplayInfo.Rotation == DisplayRotation.Rotation0 ? 0 :
                   mainDisplayInfo.Rotation == DisplayRotation.Rotation90 ? 90 :
                   mainDisplayInfo.Rotation == DisplayRotation.Rotation180 ? 180 : 270;

    activity.RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
    return rotation;
}
```

However, with this method, the screen rotates for a moment when the picture is taken.
There is no need to rotate the screen.

I only want to get the rotation status of the device without rotating the screen.

```cs
var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
var rotation = mainDisplayInfo.Rotation;
```

rotation is always 0 if you only use mainDisplayInfo without activity.RequestedOrientation.
Please help me.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with `OrientationEventListener`.

Custom a `MyOrientationEventListener` which extends `OrientationEventListener` and instantiate it in `onCreate` method.

```
[Activity(ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    private OrientationEventListener orientationEventListener;
    public static int currentOrientation;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
           ...
  
        orientationEventListener = new MyOrientationEventListener(this);
    }

    class MyOrientationEventListener : OrientationEventListener
    {
        public MyOrientationEventListener(Context context):base(context)
        {

        }
        public override void OnOrientationChanged(int orientation)
        {
            if (orientation >= 330 || orientation < 30)
            {
                currentOrientation = (int)SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0;

            }
            else if (orientation >= 60 && orientation < 120)
            {
                currentOrientation = (int)SurfaceOrientation.Rotation90;

            }
            else if (orientation >= 150 && orientation < 210)
            {
                currentOrientation = (int)SurfaceOrientation.Rotation180;

            }
            else if (orientation >= 240 && orientation < 300)
            {
                currentOrientation = (int)SurfaceOrientation.Rotation270;

            }
        }
    }

    //Enables and disables listening
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        orientationEventListener.Enable();
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        orientationEventListener.Disable();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I was able to get the Android rotation by using the OrientationListener you taught me.
It was very useful.