# How to get current orientation size in camerapagerenderer in android Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android, position, orientation, default-value

when i take zoomin and zoomout i have to given some orientation when inside the zoominfunction call these method and save camera goes to default state how to change actual position size in android xamarin

```
private void PrepareAndStartCamera()
        {
            try
            {
                camera.StopPreview();

                var display = activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay;
                if (display.Rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0)
                {
                    camera.SetDisplayOrientation(90);
                }

                if (display.Rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation270)
                {
                    camera.SetDisplayOrientation(180);
                }

                camera.StartPreview();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it and attach the link here.

Comment: @WenxuLi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68799406/when-we-try-to-zoomin-and-zoomout-on-xamarin-android-several-color-shades-are-o?noredirect=1#comment121610737_68799406 pls check the link

Comment: Check this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68450595/i-only-want-to-get-the-rotation-status-of-the-device-without-rotating-the-screen/68464933#68464933), it may help you.